# Globally recording Bash history: Dealing with long-running commands

Tags: bash, logging

For security reasons, I'm trying to remotely log all commands that users enter into the shell.  I've got it to work by using this in my global `bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a >(tee -a ~/.bash_history | logger -t "$(basename $SHELL)[$$]: ($USER)")'
```

However, each command is getting recorded only *after* it has completed.  For long-running commands such as `sudo su` or `mysql` or even `sleep 7000 && /bin/do_something_risky`, this is a problem.  So my question is: How can I log commands at the *beginning* of execution rather than at the end?  Is this possible without something really painful such as hacking the Bash source code?

(Yes, I know a user could turn off this logging by overwriting `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but we'd know something was up if they were opening shells but nothing was getting recorded.)

Comment: One thing that distinguishes this question from the one of which it is marked as a duplicate is the requirement that the entry be made at the beginning of execution. Take a look at using the `DEBUG` trap.